# How to let turtle back and forth in specific tick?

Tags: netlogo

In the beginning, I `setxy` the turtle location around the patch and then I want them to move to the specific location. When the tick goes through (just like in 4 hours and you should move to somewhere else), I want them to move to another location. Here is my code

```
turtles-own [start-patch destination work-hour rest-hour]

to setup
  clear-turtles
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 50
  ask turtles
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set start-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = pink]
    set work-hour 0
    set rest-hour 0
  ]
end


to go
  ask turtles [pick-patch]
  tick
end

to pick-patch
  set destination one-of patches with [pcolor = orange + 3]
  ifelse destination != nobody
  [
    travel
  ]
  [fd 0]
end

to travel
  if distance destination > 1
  [face destination fd random 4]
  if patch-here = destination
  [
    wander
    set work-hour work-hour + 1
  ]
  if (work-hour > 30 and distance start-patch > 1)
  [face start-patch fd random 4]
  if patch-here = start-patch
  [
    wander
    set rest-hour rest-hour + 1
  ]
end

to wander
  ifelse random 2 = 0 [rt random 60] [lt random 60]
end
```

At first, turtles are moving toward the `destination`, they move and stay there for about 200 ticks (I don't know why because I code just 30 ticks). Then they start to move to another location (which is `start-patch`). As soon as they reach to `start-patch`, they just disappear and appear in the `destination` location.

How could I fix my code and let them move back and forth like a routine?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have several basic logic problems. (1) your go procedure calls the pick-patch procedure. So the destination is always changing. (2) When you check if work hours > 30, you also check the distance. What happens if the work hours > 30 and the distance is < 1, but it's not actually on the start-patch? Your code just ignores the existence of those turtles. (3) You never reset the work and rest hours to 0.

You need to do some logic debugging. Try inspecting one of your turtles and look at the variables each tick and think through what that turtle is being asked to do by the code compared to what you really want it to do. Or reduce your number of turtles to 1, so you can get the code to tell you what's going on with statements like:

```
ask turtles
[ type "my location is: " print patch-here
  type " going to: " print destination
  type "worked for: " print work-hour
]
```